# php facebook feed

Tags: php, facebook

Hi im having some trouble. I am trying to get my feed from a certain facebook page the code looks like this:

```
<?php
//Get the contents of the Facebook page
try
{    
$FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/hereihaveenteredcorrectpageid
/feed?access_token=hereihaveenteredcorrectaccesstoken');
}catch{
echo "Load Failed";       
}  
//Interpret data with JSON
$FBdata = json_decode($FBpage);
echo "$FBdata";
//Loop through data for each news item
foreach ($FBdata->data as $news ) {
//Explode News and Page ID's into 2 values
$StatusID = explode("_", $news->id);
echo '<li>';
//Check for empty status (for example on shared link only)
echo $news->message;
echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

I have checked the url and I get correct feed in my browser when i enter the url, but there is nothing showing on my site. This code witout the try catch returns the page but no feed at all, this code with try catch returns blank page(wordpress). I can't understand whats wrong and why I can't get the feed.

I've tried to echo the $FBpage and the $FBdata after the json, but it returns nothing, just as if the feed is empty...no error messages.

So the problem is the get_file_contents somewhere... It just dosen't work. Please help me I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have a blank page is because you have a parse error in your `try  {} .. catch {}` statement. It should be:

```
}catch (Exception $ex){
```

Comment: I've solved the problem via Curl instead of file_get_contents